# Simple ODE matrix question

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

I am doing my homework and I know this is a very simple construction but I am unsure how to do this.

We are given $x''+x=0$ and are supposed to write it in the form $x'=Ax$. I see to go to $x''=-x$ but then how do I differentiate it properly? I know ultimately it ends up as a system of sines and cosines but my knowledge of solving linear systems is not that advanced and I am having trouble finding reading material on the internet. If you fully integrate the function in respect to x and t I believe it is -lnx=t. But this seems incorrect and does not give me an idea of how to construct a matrix to solve for $PDP^{-1}$. Thanks!

Comment: Introduce a new variable $u=x'$ and convert to a system of two equations.

Comment: To do this would I want to make x'' = $u^2$ or something like x''+u=-x and then u=0 as my system?

Comment: The goal is to eliminate explicit second derivatives of $x$.

Comment: so then can I substitute $u^2$ for x''? Would it be best to convert everything in terms of the new variable and then solve that way? some u=0 and then u^2=-u'?

Comment: Where is this $u^2$ coming from? $x''=u'$.

Comment: I was thinking $u^2$ would be equivalent to the x term. To put it all in terms of u.

Comment: What might be confusing you is that $x$ stands for two different things in your problem statement. In the differential equation $x''+x=0$, $x$ is a *scalar* function; in $x'=Ax$ it is a *vector*. To keep these separate, let’s reword the problem: Write $x''+x=0$ in the form $\mathbf y'=A\mathbf y$. Your original function $x$ and the function $u=x'$ that we’ve introduced are the components of the vector $\mathbf y$.

Comment: Ok. So we can leave the scalar x in terms of itself and not convert it. so we can have u'=-x. and then x''=u'. Or do we need different vectors since you said we want to eliminate x''? or do we take x'=u?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re using $x$ to stand for two different things—a scalar function and a vector function—which appears to be part of what’s confusing you. Let’s call the vector function something else: The task is to write $x''+x=0$ in the form $\mathbf y'=A\mathbf y$. We do this by reducing the second derivative of $x$ to a first derivative: introduce the new function $u=x'$, so that $x''=u'$. You then have the system of first-order equations $$x'=u\\u'=-x$$ which can be written in matrix form as $$\begin{bmatrix}x'\\u'\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\u\end{bmatrix}.$$